# How can we upgrade database in sqlite which is in assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite

How can we upgrade database in sqlite which is in assets folder

I am trying to upgrade a database which is in assets folder

Using the mozilla plugin for sqlite manager I have changed both

schema version and user version

Now when I try to access the database it shows the old data

what exactly should be done in onupgrade

here is the dpbhelper class

```
public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH;

    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;

        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }

        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {



        Log.w(ExternalDbOpenHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion  + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_NAME);
        onCreate(database);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the asset file contains *initial* data, and the actual database might contain new data entered by the user, then you want to upgrade the database without deleting the new data.
The only way to do this is with an upgrade script.

If the database is read only, you want to delete the old one, and just copy the new one. The easiest way to do this is to give the new database a different file name.

Comment: while the solution does work , it is very non technical(for a lack of proper word), way of doing things, but that is one of the many faults that android carries.